# Replace Variables with issue as empty String

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a HTML Text, which will have some Thymeleaf variables.
If I have some unknown variables etc. I will get always an error message an the String will not replace with variables anymore.
I would like to replace the values for which I got an error just with an empty String ("").
How can I do this?

Here a simple test: customer. (with dot) is an issue for Thymeleaf, therefore I will get an error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    StringTemplateResolver templateResolver = new StringTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);

    // Erstelle eine Template-Engine
    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

    String templateString = "<p>Hello, {{customer.name}} !</p>";

    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setName("Meier");

    Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariable("customer.", customer);

    templateString = replaceCustomVariableSyntax(templateString);

    // Prozessiere das Template mit den Variablen
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    try {
        templateEngine.process(templateString, context, stringWriter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Catch any exceptions and return an empty string
    }

    System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
}
```